# Mocha Tests unexpected error

Tags: solidity, testing, mocha, chai

My tests where running well but not when I run `yarn hardhat test`, I get the error below.

##### Error

```bash
An unexpected error occurred:

TypeError: describe is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/k_frankline/projects/ICO/test/ico.js:8:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at /Users/k_frankline/projects/ICO/node_modules/hardhat/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:414:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/k_frankline/projects/ICO/node_modules/hardhat/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:411:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I think it's a dependency issue. I have tried different versions of mocha but nothing works.

What could be the issue?

##### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "ico",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/kihiuFrank/ICO.git",
  "author": "kihiuFrank <franklinekihiu@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.4",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.3.0-beta.13",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.0.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.8.0",
    "@pinata/sdk": "^1.1.23",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.1.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.2",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.0",
    "base64-sol": "^1.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "ethers": "^5.5.3",
    "hardhat": "^2.14.0",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.9.29",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.2",
    "ts-node": ">=8.0.0",
    "typechain": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are facing a similar error check answer here; 
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/5384